# How do I open the chest in the Library?

Tags: count-lucanor

Attempting to use the chest in the library tells me

> It's locked... Perhaps I should wait for the right time to distract the Camerlengo.

The clock in the same room is usable and if you use it, Camerlengo will walk over to it.

However, trying to open it while he's distracted gives you the same message as before.  You also can't seem to pickpocket him.

How exactly do you open this chest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wait under the table long enough, Camerlengo will open the chest on his own.

He seems to do this right after looking at the book on the table, so as soon as he turns toward the chest, go run to the clock and use it, then go through the tunnel and around to the open chest.